# NoMethodError in Users#index 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, nomethoderror

I'm getting a NoMethodError in Users#Index with an 'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass' for the line below:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
```

I'm not sure where the problem resides. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance. I know I am missing something extremely easy here.

**User/Index**

```
<div class="page-header">
<center><strong><h1> All Users </h1></strong></center>
</div>

    <div class="row">
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <div class="horizontal-align col-md-2">
            <div class="user">
                <center><%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %></center>
                <center><br><%= link_to user.name, user %></br></center>
                <% if current_user.admin %>
                <center><%= link_to "Delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></center>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="center">
<%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
</div>
```

**User/Show**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>

 <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
        <section>
            <h1>
                <%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:thumb) %>
                <%= @user.name %>
            </h1>


    <section>
      <%= render 'users/stats' %>
    </section>


    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'users/unfollow' %>
    <% else %>
    <%= render 'users/follow' %>
    <% end %>
```

**User/Controller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


   def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
   end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user 

      @posts = @user.posts.order("updated_at DESC")
      render actions: :show
    else
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
  end  
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_path 
  end

  def admin_user
      redirect_to root_path unless current_user.admin?
  end
```

end

Comment: What file is the error getting raised in?  The error backtrace will tell you. Show the code around the failure in your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error `NoMethodError` means that you are calling a method that doesn't exist for the given class. In this case it is `nil:NilClass` which, obvious, doesn't contain the method `each` because it is `nil`! So let's examine:

You are calling `@users.each` which is calling the error. Since it says that the method if undefined for nil (as described above) it tells us that on the `index` page, `@users` is `nil` (probably not what it is intended to be!).

So it looks like the problem rests in your definition of `@users`. I'm not entirely sure, but it looks as though, in your `UsersController` that you have an extra `end` after the `def following` which would cause the controller to end prematurely, and therefore not define `@users`. (You can test that by changing it to `@users = User.all` which should work).

Let me know how things turn out

Comment: oh, very nice spotting.

Comment: You probably have to add an `end` to the very end of the file.

Comment: @Vasseurth Nice! I completely missed that. Thank you!